# Can the Geb baseUrl navigation be used with subdomains?

Tags: grails, geb

I'm using Geb to write some browser automation tests. It allows you to configure a `baseUrl` and specify browser actions relative to this, as detailed in [The Book of Geb](http://www.gebish.org/manual/0.7.0/browser.html#the_base_url). This works nicely for paths within the site but I can't see any syntax for dealing with subdomains.

Is there a simple way of going from `baseUrl = http://myapp.com/` to `http://sub.myapp.com` using the Geb DSL or am I going to have to grab the property that defines the baseUrl in code and use it to generate the subdomain?

Comment: what exactly are you trying to achieve? run the same tests against different domains or switch domains within the same set of tests?

Comment: I'm trying to switch to a subdomain of my baseUrl as part of a test. So I have a Page object where the url is defined relative to the baseUrl (eg. url = "signup/" which is equivalent to <baseUrl>/signup) I want to define another page object that whose url is a subdomain of the baseUrl (eg. account.<baseUrl>). I can populate that value in code but am just wondering if there is an easy way in the DSL (that I am missing) to specify it. The baseUrl property is useful for testing across a number of different environments.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As stated by erdi there seems to be no way to currently do it. In the end we added an overridden version of getPageUrl() to our subclass of Page.

```
String getPageUrl() {
    def subdomainPresent = this.class.declaredFields.find {
        it.name == 'subdomain' && isStatic(it.modifiers)
    }
    if( subdomainPresent ) {
        def baseURL = getBrowser().getConfig().getBaseUrl()
        def splicePoint = baseURL.indexOf('//') + 1

        pageUrl = baseURL[0..splicePoint] + this.class.subdomain + "." + baseURL[splicePoint+1..-1] + pageUrl
    }
    pageUrl
}
```

Used like this for account.{baseUrl}/login

```
class MyPage extends MyPageBase{
    static subdomain = "account"
    static url = "login"
}
```

Documented here as a pull request https://github.com/geb/geb/pull/37/files

Answer (score 1):

In Geb the Browser class has this method:

```
    /**
 * Changes the base url used for resolving relative urls.
 * <p>
 * This method delegates to {@link geb.Configuration#setBaseUrl}.
 */
void setBaseUrl(String baseUrl) {
    config.baseUrl = baseUrl
}
```

[Geb Javadoc](http://www.gebish.org/manual/0.9.1/api/geb/Browser.html#setBaseUrl%28java.lang.String%29)

I successfully use it to switch server contexts of the same application.

E.g: 
     `browser.setBaseUrl('http://int/app/pages/') 
      browser.setBaseUrl('http://ci/sameapp/pages/')`

If you are running tests using Spock this needs to be done before each feature as it gets reset.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know there is no way to modify `baseUrl` during test execution other than by directly setting it in the config:

```
browser.config.baseUrl = 'http://sub.myapp.com'
```

Comment: Thanks, yeah we came to the same conclusion and implemented the feature in code as expanded on in my answer.